# Can't control brightness on acer V3 (LINUX)

Tags: linux, brightness

I have one problem with linux mint and my conputer ACER v3, I can't control brightness, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly caused by GRUB bootloader. Running following commands might help.

```
sudo sed "s/\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\)\"\"/\1\"acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor\"/" /etc/default/grub -i 

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```